# How to drive 1 x 168 LCD using 4 x 32 LCD driver?

Tags: microcontroller, lcd, 7segmentdisplay

I have to drive an LCD that has only single `COM` and 166 segments:

[image]

[image]

Somehow using [4 x 32 LCD driver](https://www.holtek.com/documents/10179/116711/HT1621v321.pdf):

[image]

So I am going to use five such LCD drivers (32+32+32+32+32+32) by using only one `COM0` from each of them tied all together with LCD's common but not sure whether it will work?

Do I understand correct that LCD driver operates in following way: it keeps `COM` constantly `HIGH` (5V) while asserting SEGMENTS pins down to GND he wants to turn ON?

**EDIT:**
question changed - i would like to understand whether 1x168 LCD might be driven by 6 pcs of 4x32 LCD driver?

**EDIT2:**
found some piece of schematic of 4x60 LCD driver with 1x54 LCD. Looks like driver's `COMs` may be tied all together:

[image]

as explained in comments looks like LCD driver can be used with LCD having less amount of segments and commons. Thank you.

**EDIT 4:**

Seems I found cascaded LCD driver that will do the trick as suggested from comments:

[image]

Thanks a lot guys! You saved me from a fatal mistake!

Comment: 4x32 is 128, it seems you don't have enough pins to drive all the segments.

Comment: @Lior Bilia, oh, sure, 5 x 32  + 6 directly from MCU. Will it work?

Comment: Edit your question to reflect that, it still says 4x32. Alternately, for so many digits, a graphical LCD with a controller would be easier to drive.

Comment: Why must you use the HT1621? That's making things more difficult than they need to be

Comment: @Reinderien, was unable to find LCD driver that able to drive 1x168 LCD.

Comment: I'm less concerned about you needing multiple drivers and more concerned about every one of your drivers needing a chip-select input. There are other serial multiplexing schemes that would not require this and could be trivially daisy-chained.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't have time right now to answer both things you're asking here ("does the driver work this way?" and "can I drive the remaining segments straight from the MCU?"), but I can answer one of them.

---

Driving an LCD directly from an MCU isn't a great idea.

LCD segments *can* be driven by a DC voltage, but this is not recommended as it will cause damage to the LCD over time (and not a terribly long time either, I believe. Maybe even just a few hours.). The proper way to drive an LCD is with an AC voltage, flipping polarity at a high frequency. The IC you mention generates appropriate drive signals using an internal oscillator, and if you wanted to drive the remaining segments from the MCU you would have to also use some sort of oscillator to produce the correct AC signal.

That's not impossible, and not really even very hard, but it would be easier to just use one more driver. Or even better, a different driver.

---

As @Justme commented below, it looks like the driver you propose might not be usable for this LCD anyway--the HT1621 expects multiple common terminals, and I'm not sure you can use it for something with a single common.

Comment: The display has one common and 168 individual segments. Thus it can be driven with single HT1621 with 4 commons and 32 segments. And they have no syncronization pins so multiple chips can't be chained. At least a chainable chip should be used to get 1 common and 168 segments.

Comment: @Justme I didn't give that last paragraph a whole lot of thought, nor did I worry much about whether the proposed driver would work at all--I was mostly wanting to advise the asker about how you need AC to drive an LCD. I'll remove the stuff at the end.

Comment: This answer is actually a very important piece, because if they were ordinary digital signals then connect 128 individual segments to qty 32 of 1:4 mux, with the select bits generated from COM[1:4] by a priority encoder, and the single COM generated from COM[1:4] by an AND gate.  That's a lot more trouble than using the correct driver chip, of course.  But massively more complicated if signals are continuously varying instead of quantized.

Comment: @BenVoigt They are quantized; an LCD is usually driven with a square wave because that's simpler. But it has to go both positive and negative, which logic circuits generally don't do.

Comment: @Justme, could you please share some light why multiple LCD drivers can't be tied to same common of LCD? I was thinking that COMMON pin of LCD is constantly HIGH? Am I mistaken?

Comment: @user3583807 The common pin is pulsed to multiplex the display. That allows you to control 128 segments with a single HT1621.

Comment: Thank you very much, @Hearth! Now it is clear for me!